# Find UI components in real time run, under Android OS, it is possible?

Tags: android

I want to know if I can find/reach UI components of running application under Android OS.
it is possible to catch the Button/DDL/.. that was clicked by the user in real-time,

example from other subject(web):
In browser I can listen to the events and catch the DOM object that was clicked,
in this way I can save the DOM object data.

catching UI components that was changed by the user will give the option to save UI component
data, and to perform the user actions automatic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy standard way to intercept all events that are send to the UI, especially if you try to intercept things not sent to your application.